# Multiple selection from grid in ionic framework

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, multiple-select

I want to make a grid of categories images, select multiple categories from them  and send their values to controller. I don't know how to achieve this with ionic framework.

Here is my view:

```
 <ion-view  cache-view="false">
 <div class="bar login-bar bar-header bar-stable">
   <h1 class="title ttl-log-bar">Welcome</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="bar bar-subheader welcome-subhead">
   <h2 class="title welc-sub-h2">What do you like to shop for?</h2>
   <h5 class="title welc-sub-h5">Pick at least one category</h5>
 </div>
   <ion-content scroll="true" class="has-header has-subheader">
     <div class="row row-cat" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
       <div class="col col-cat col-50" ng-repeat="items in categoryList">
         <img ng-src="{{items.image}}" width="100%" />
       </div>
     </div>       
   </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add on img tag ng-click with function passing e.g. ID like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{items.image}}" ng-click="selectCategory(items.id)" />
```

Then in controller define this function

```
$scope.selectedCategory = [];
$scope.selectCategory = function(id){
  var index = $scope.selectedCategory.indexOf(id);
  if(index === -1){
     $scope.selectedCategory.push(id);
  }else{
     $scope.selectedCategory.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Then you can us selectedCategory array as a collection of selected item's IDs

Comment: What if the user unselect the image?

Comment: then index of id will be different then -1 so ID will be remove from array

this is this line of code :  selectedCategory.splice(index, 1);

Basically it works that if ID is not in array it will add it to this array, but if ID is already in array it will remove it.

Comment: I forgot to add $scope inside function - fixed

Comment: Genius solution. But there is a problem when i unselect the selected img it is removing the last added item from array. it should unselect the clicked item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103105/discussion-between-salman-ullah-and-przemek).

Comment: still same result
when i click first img: [1] 
when i click second img : [1,2] 
when i again click on frist img: [1]
but the result should be
when i click first img: [1] 
when i click second img : [1,2] 
when i again click on frist img: [2]